# Redirect page using ajax ipgeolocation.io

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, geolocation, ip-geolocation

I was using freegeoip.net and now need to migrate to [ipgeolocation.io](https://ipgeolocation.io/) to change an action form to redirect the page if country code is `DO`

This code was working ok, but this service is deprecated and has been shut down since yesterday. I'm trying to use `ipgeolocation` with my ApiKey but this not working:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.ipgeolocation.io/ipgeo?apiKey=XXXXXXXXXXX',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(location) {
        if (location.country_code2 == 'DO') {
            $('#formsearchp').attr('action', '/dominicans.asp');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Please update your code to look like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
url: 'https://api.ipgeolocation.io/ipgeo?apiKey=XXXXXXXXXXX',
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(location) {
    if (location.country_code2 == 'DO') {
        $('#formsearchp').attr('action', '/dominicans.asp');
    }
}
});
```

What were you doing wrong?
This api does not support post request. I changed it to GET. It does not support jsonp, so I have changed data type to json. Everything else in your code is fine and should work.

Disclaimer: I'm associated with ipgeolocation.io. If you face any issue, let me know by commenting here. You can also contact our support channel thru email support@ipgeolocation.io or live chat on our site.